# 2D Positioning Localization

Tags: encoder, math, gyro, robot

I have a robot. My robot has three main sensors one is a gyro from which i can get my yaw, pitch, and roll. I also have an encoder in the x and y axis. How can I use these sensors together to reliably get my (x, y) coordinate within half an inch.

Just to clarify

Given: I have a gyro, an encoder on my drivetrain, and an encoder perpendicular to the drivetrain.

Problem: Use these three sensors to reliably get (x, y) position accounting for rotation on a global x and y axis. What I mean by: Account for rotation is that my position should not change if I spin in a circle, only if my physical x and y coordinates change. The resolution I am looking for is within half an inch. I would like the (x, y) to be relative to my starting position and in inches.

Question: How in the world do I approach this, I'm a beginner when it comes to sensor fusion, sensors in general and most of robotics.

Comment: Look up *Kalman filter*. Be prepared for a lot of math.

Comment: Define what form you want the XY position to be in. Then define the signals that are the inputs and how these signals relate to the real world. Then all you need to do is design the black box that connects inputs with outputs. Nobody is going to help you design the block box without IO specified and understood.

Comment: The inputs is the data from the three sensors and the output is the (x, y) coordinate in inches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question: How in the world do I approach this, I'm a beginner when it
>   comes to sensor fusion, sensors in general and most of robotics.

You approach this with a kalman filter. The kalman filter keeps track of the state of the system. To do this it is best to have a knowledge of signal processing\theory as you will need to come up with a [model of the system states](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwiZ_eiH38ncAhXeHzQIHWVbBewQFjACegQIABAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftechteach.no%2Ffag%2Fseky3322%2F0708%2Fkalmanfilter%2Fkalmanfilter.pdf&usg=AOvVaw10xS9vdt7AGLzclg-HQJ2L). There are [many resources](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1&ei=DIxgW5nHIN6_0PEP5baV4A4&q=kalman%20filter%20tutrial%20sensor%20fusion&oq=kalman%20filter%20tutrial%20sensor%20fusion&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i13i30k1.503990.512540.0.513125.43.39.1.0.0.0.362.4176.5j22j3j1.31.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..11.32.4174...0j0i10k1j0i30k1j0i10i30k1j0i67k1j0i13k1j0i22i30k1j33i22i29i30k1.0.lo0skSv8jZM) to enable you to do this. To explain how a kalman filter works is beyond the scope of this fourm as a few weeks could be spent on learning how they work.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Comment: Me upvoting is not publicly viewed, not enough reputation lol.